# how to share and get the google+ comments of the same post using javascript

Tags: javascript, post, google-api, google-plus

how to share and get the google+ comments of the same post using javascript.
I have created app using google api console.

for login i have used the code:

```
<body>    
<div id="signin-button" class="show">    
<div class="g-signin" data-callback="loginFinishedCallback" 
data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity" 
data-approvalprompt="force" 
data-clientid="MY_CLIENT_ID-u5ec5s5s43pc7485ab278l4dd6l2uctb@developer.gserviceaccount.com" 
data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read" 
data-height="short" data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin">
</div>    
</div>    
</body
```

Comment: can you give me sample code to share post and get comments(done by google plus user) for the same post

Comment: @RajeshDhiman clientids are not considered secret.